# From previous state version to hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to manipulate the api response in order to render cleaner way as posible.

I have this state:

```
 state = {
        tasks: {
          workingProgress: [],
          toDo: [],
          done: [],
        
        },
     };
```

And from api I get objects like these:

```
{id: "1", task: "add button", team: "Metro", status: "workingProgress", …}
{id: "8", task: "fixed accessibility SR", team: "Metro", status: "toDo", …}
```

My idea is transform my state in something like this:

```
tasks: {
          workingProgress: [{id: "1", task: "add button", team: "Metro", ...},{}, {}],
          toDo: [{id: "8", task: "fixed accessibility SR", team: "Metro", ...}, {}, {}],
          done: [],
        
        },
```

I have this and works as a charm:

```
state = {
    tasks: {
      workingProgress: [],
      toDo: [],
      done: [],
    
    },
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    TasksAPI.getAll().then((res) => {
      this.setState(({ tasks }) => {
        res.forEach((item) => {
          if (tasks[item.status]) {
            tasks[item.status].push(item);
          }
        });
        return { tasks };
      });
    });
  }
```

My question is because I intend to change from "setState" code from **hooks**.

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState({
    workingProgress: [],
    toDo: [],
    done: [],
  });
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    TasksAPI.getAll().then((res) => {
      setTasks(({ tasks }) => {
        res.forEach((item) => {
          if (tasks[item.status]) {
            tasks[item.status].push(item);
          }
        });
        return { tasks };
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

But when I try this my code is break:

> Tasks.js:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'toDo' of undefined

This is my return:

```
<div>
 {Object.entries(tasks).map(([key, status]) => (
   <div key={key}>
    <div >
     <ol>
      {status.map((item) => (
       <li>
        <div>
       ......

</div>
```

Is my "hooks" approach incorrect?

Comment: your arrow function in setTask doesn't return anything therefor setTask wont be set to anything

Comment: @Breezer oh, sorry I miscopied the code, it was there. Let me edit my question

Comment: it probably renders before tasks are set, do a if state of tasks around your render and show perhaps a loading bar while its false, or you could do a async await which would wait for the data before it continues the operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies inside the code of your `useEffect` and specifically `setTasks(({ tasks }) =>...` and `return { tasks };`, which have 2 main problems:

1. In this piece of code you create a local `tasks` variable that overiddes your `tasks` from state, returned by `useState`.
2. You also trying to destruct this state and grab `tasks` property but this is wrong since your state is already the tasks. You carried this logic from the previous implementation where your `state` was an object containing a `tasks` property.

Your useEffect should be changed like below:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    TasksAPI.getAll().then((res) => {
      setTasks((previousTasks) => {
        const newTasks = {...previousTasks}
        res.forEach((item) => {
          if (newTasks[item.status]) {
            newTasks[item.status] = [...newTasks[item.status], item]
          }
        });
        return newTasks;
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

`newTasks = [...previousTasks]` and `newTasks[item.status] = [...newTasks[item.status], item]` ensure that you don't mutate the previous tasks object and status arrays and create new ones.

Even your 1st solution (with classes) does not tackle this problem which can lead to bugs with react updates.

However if you don't care about deep immutability you can simplify the code inside `forEach` to (although i wouldn't advise so):

```
  if (newTasks[item.status]) {
    newTasks[item.status].push(item);
  }
```

Comment: this could be the solution, but when I try it I'm getting this error now:
```Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance```

Comment: that is an incompatibility with some tool versions that I have, right?

Comment: Indeed @Iván. I should have written `const newTasks = {...previousTasks}` instead of `const newTasks = [...previousTasks]` . I made an edit.

Comment: Thank you for your help, works as expected !

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

From what I can see you've a simple state mutation issue. The effect hook callback is for-each'ing over the `res` array and directly pushing into the `tasks` state instead of creating new array and state references.

You are also attempting to destructure `tasks` *from* the `tasks` state, which of obviously not a defined property. When it was `this.state.tasks` and "previousState" was `this.state` you could destructure `tasks`, but now in the `useState` hook `tasks` ***is*** the state! You then return an object `return { tasks };` with a single `tasks` property with the real state nested deeper, i.e. making it `tasks.tasks.toDo` for example.

## Solution

Instead of looping through and enqueueing multiple state updates, which necessarily need to correctly update from each previously enqueued update, just loop though and create the new next state object and enqueue a single state update.

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState({
  workingProgress: [],
  toDo: [],
  done: [],
});

useEffect(() => {
  TasksAPI.getAll()
    .then((res) => {
      setTasks(tasks => res.reduce(
        (tasks, task) => ({
          ...tasks,                        // <-- shallow copy the state
          [task.status]: [
            ...(tasks[task.status] ?? []), // <-- shallow copy array
            task                           // <-- append new task item
          ],
        }),
        tasks,                             // <-- start from the previous state
      ));
  });
}, []);
```